# Check if point x=0 is a point of removable discontinuity of function

Tags: functions

I have few functions and have to decide if x=0 is a point of removable discontinuity of function.

[image]

And this is right for number 1 and number 3, because one side limits are same, whereas in number 2, left limit is 0 and right limit is 1, so it is not removable discontinuity, but jump +1.

I am right? thx a lot

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Thank you, sir. :)

Comment: , you are right!